# How to toggle state by unique string in react redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I am creating a list inside the Component file dynamically by mapping data from a JSON response with the help of thunk middleware.
I want to select elements from that list and add them to "My Favorites",
My JSON response doesn't have a unique ID but a unique string.

Reducer:

```
   const initialstate = { isFav: false }
   const reducer = (state=initialstate, action) => {
   switch(action.type){
   case actionTypes.TOGGLE_FAVORITE:
             return {
              ...state,
              isFav: **What to do here?**
             }
                     
         default:
             break;
         }
    }

export default reducer;
```

Action.js:

```
export const TOGGLE_FAVORITE = 'TOGGLE_FAVORITE';
export const togglefav = (url) =>{
    return{
        type: TOGGLE_FAVORITE,
        payload: url
    }
}
```

Component.js

```
this.props.dailySource.map((source,index) =>{
...
<div className={classes.star}>
            <span className="fa fa-star" key={index} onClick={()=>             
            this.props.onToggleFavorite(source.url) }
            style={{ color: (this.props.toggleFav) ? 'red' : '' }}></span>
            </div>
}
}))

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
  return{
    dailySource: state.list.newsItem,
    toggleFav: state.list.isFav 
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
  return{
    onToggleFavorite: (url) => dispatch (actionCreators.togglefav(url))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you can simplify your pattern.

Instead of extracting isFav to another state tree, it would be much easier if you put it inside the objects of the list itself.

Let's see the code.

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = [];

const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case actionTypes.TOGGLE_FAVORITE:
            const dailySource = [...state].map((v) => {
                if (v.url === action.url) {
                    v.isFav = true;
                }
            return v;
            });
            return dailySource;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**Component**

```
this.props.dailySource.map((source,index) =>{
<div className={classes.star}>
            <span className="fa fa-star" key={index} onClick={()=>             
            this.props.onToggleFavorite(source.url) }
            style={{ color: source.isFav ? 'red' : '' }}></span>
            </div>
}
}))
```

Comment: That's a good approach. Even though it didn't work, I am closer to the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify on why it didn't work and I will elaborate further also. Can even do a mini repo fyi. Thanks